Как генерировать текст, исходя из того образца, что находится в файле БЕЗ использования сторонних библиотек?
Возможно меня кто-то не так мог понять, но я имею ввиду именно генерацию текста, исходя из многострочного образца с кучей данных (txt файл) НЕ используя сторонних библиотек (базовые можно). Я уже сделал 2 нейросети, которые используют цифры для коммуникации (Например, предсказать следующее число или понять из веса и роста, взрослый человек, или нет), но теперь я хочу понять - как сделать полноценный текстовый чат-бот? Или хотя-бы обычный генератор текста, исходя из уже упомянутого файла.
